# Automatically Go to the next line of a multiline text box

Tags: windows, arrays, winforms, powershell

I have a windows form into which im updating a text from powershell, just like a scripts progress status, im trying to auto move to a new line into the textbox but im unable to do that

I tried [System.Environment]::NewLine but it did not work

`$nl = [System.Environment]::NewLine`

`$i++`

`$textbox1.Text = "PS $i> Running Script"`

`$textbox1.AppendText($nl)`

[image]

Could Any of you guys helpe me out on how to move the cursor automatically to the next line
Maybe Show

PS2> Script Started

Comment: Honestly? I cannot explain that behaviour unless there was something that would convert U+000a to `\n` and U+000d to `\r` before it writes to that textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution

```
$textbox1.AppendText("PS $i> Running Script`r`n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$nl = "`r`n"
$i++
$textbox1.Text = "PS $i> Running Script"
$textbox1.AppendText($nl)
```